# Is there any option for debugging a service independently in android project?

Tags: android, debugging, interface, aidl

In my project i'm using several .aidl interfaces but while debugging this is not crossing the aidl boundary???

Can i do debugging for the Android Interface  Definition Language (.AIDL) independently???

Answer (score 0):

You can debug AIDL using `Remote Java Application` configuration in debug menu.

What you need to set:

- host as `localhost`
- port corresponding to process port (can be seen in DDMS/Device tab).